# Jquery mobile handler event button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new coding, so please don't be mad at this simple question, But, I have a button that I want to change the text from the header and content with onclick. But, I have no idea how to do it.

I have a button in my page like this:

```
 <button id="myButton" data-role="button">
```

And also have the function in java:

```
$("#myButton").click(function()){ 
}
```

So, if my header div has an id as "`myHeader`" and content id is "`myContent`", How can I make the callback function to modify the text?

Answer (score 0):

if I got it your html should look like this:

```
<div id="myHeader"></div>
<div id="myContent"></div>
<button id="myButton" data-role="button">
```

**'And also have the function in java:'** you are not using java, this is javascript wich is really different from java.

so your script should look like this:

```
$("#myButton").click(function()){ 
    $('#myHeader').html('hello World');
    $('#myContent').html('hey let me say hello too!');
}
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

@bto.rdz is correct but his jquery syntax is a bit off. The function has an extra parentheses that should be at the end instead with a semi-colon afterward.

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){ 
  $('#myHeader').html('hello World');
  $('#myContent').html('hey let me say hello too!');
});
```